# iOS 11, Xcode 9 Error: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting  Error: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
 in iOS 11, Xcode 9 when i am going to background and wifi off.. its getting continuously up to wifi on and any one have a solution.

Comment: the above error is related to AWSCore`__63-[AWSTask continueWithExecutor:successBlock:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke:

Comment: this may solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868844/5032981

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Maybe it's one of those crazy iOS 11 bugs, because I got the exact same problem after upgrading to 11.2. The reason was that the cellular data for the app had been set to false on the device for some reason. To fix it, just goto the settings app, and cellular. Find your app in the list and enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the permission about you app, when it is only wifi, the issue will be caused in the 4G networking.